# What's the supported and recommended way to connect Windows 10 via VPN to a Fritz!Box?

Tags: vpn, fritzbox

I'm going mad.

I'm trying to get VPN connection to work from my Windows 10 pro laptop to my office Fritz!Box? router.

The VPN access works flawlessly from my iPhone and from macOS, but I don't get it to work on Windows.

With the Windows built-in VPN client I get on connection attempt:

> The l2tp connection attempt failed because security policy for the connection was not found.

Based on solution recommendations for this error message I added:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PolicyAgent RegValue: AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule Type: DWORD Data Value: 2
```

But that didn't resolve the issue.

I then downloaded and installed the Fritz!Fernzugang software from here:
https://avm.de/service/vpn/uebersicht/

But when trying to launch, I get the error:

> "Could no find the AVM VPN Driver. No connections can be established."

I tried following these steps (even though they are for Windows 7/8):

https://en.avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-7330/knowledge-base/publication/show/221_Error-message-Could-not-find-the-AVM-VPN-driver/

But after that I just get a message:

> Registration at the Fritz!VPN Service failed

Finally I tried to connect using an old "Shrew Soft VPN" client (for Windows 2000/XP!!) as instructed here: https://avm.de/service/vpn/tipps-tricks/vpn-verbindung-zur-fritzbox-mit-shrew-soft-vpn-client-einrichten/

With that I can establish a connection and if a connection is established, I can at least access the Fritz!Box? admin console (on http://fritz.box/) so something seems to work, but I cannot ping any of my other machines in the network.

So whats the supported and recommended way to connect from Windows 10 via VPN to a network behind a Fritz!Box? router?

Answer (score 0):

The supported and recommended way is documented on the Fritz website [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220525195021/https://en.avm.de/service/vpn/how-to-tips/setting-up-a-vpn-connection-to-fritzbox-in-windows-fritzvpn/).

I know steps are meant to be copied into SF answers, but the steps are long and may change in the future. The gist of it is you download and install their client, generate the configuration file, then apply it.